# PHP switch statement with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have some problem to create a preg_match() inside my switch statement.

I want to write preg_match that match /oop/page/view/[some-number].

For now its working like:

If I run in my browser http://example.com/oop/page/view/1 its shows '404 page'.
And when I run some address for example http://example.com/oop/page/view/test or even /oop/test its run 2nd case and dont know yet how. For sure something is wrong in my regex expresion..

```
public function check(){
    $url = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'url');
    switch ($url) {
        case '':
            echo 'HomePage';
            break;
        case preg_match('#^/oop/page/view/\d+$#', $url):
            echo $url;
            break;
        default:
            echo '404 page';
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Along with the inproper use of the `switch`, `^/oop/page/view/\d+$` wont match `http://example.com/oop/page/view/1` because of the `^` anchor. Remove the `^` and it should work. https://3v4l.org/lHgqm

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks for answer, but as You can see I'm not checking full addres with http:// but just only url param what is in my case equal to $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

Comment: OK, get used to showing accurate data, what variables contain etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do instead is something like this:

```
switch (true) {
  case preg_match(...):
```

I don't remember if switch in PHP is strict or loose comparison, but if it's strict, just put a `!!` in front of each case to convert it to boolean.

Comment: Note:
Note that switch/case does loose comparison. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Also needs to change the first case to `case $url == '':`

Comment: @Brad Thanks, changed switch($url) to switch(true) and it's works !

Comment: True about the switch, however the pattern doesn't match the input.

Answer (score 1):

A switch statement compares each `case` expression to the original expression in the `switch()`. So

```
case preg_match('#^/oop/page/view/\d+$#', $url):
```

is analogous to:

```
if ($url == preg_match('#^/oop/page/view/\d+$#', $url))
```

This is clearly not what you want. If you want to test different kinds of expressions, don't use `switch()`, use `if/elseif/else`:

```
if ($url == '') {
    echo 'Homepage';
} elseif (preg_match('#^/oop/page/view/\d+$#', $url)) {
    echo $url;
} else {
    echo '404 page';
}
```

Comment: `switch()` is actually totally appropriate for a list of things where you only want one match, or with cases to be grouped together (without `break`).  It's the proper control structure.  See my answer for a way to do this.

Comment: @Brad I generally consider that inverted `switch/case` to be a perversion. The only situation where it provides any benefit is if you need fall-through without `break`, but that's very rare.

Comment: @Brad Grouping conditions together can be done with `||` in `if()`.

Comment: You might reconsider.  Sure, all sorts of control structures are abused, but using a switch/case in this case best communicates what's going on.  If there were just a list of strings, you'd probably use switch/case, right?  This is no different, except that we're matching via RegEx.  The logic and use case is identical... just with different ways of specifying the string to match.

Comment: What's perverted is using `switch(true)` at the beginning. The logic of `switch` is you have a variable and you want to test it against numerous values. Many languages don't even allow expressions in `case`, they have to be constants -- it's a dispatch table.

Comment: Sure, and perhaps you want to test it in other ways.  There's nothing wrong with `switch(true)`.  This is PHP.  Other languages aren't relevant.  If you think `switch(true)` is perverted, I can only imagine what you think about the rest of PHP.  :-)